# Dropbox gone from indicator area after upgrade to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, unity, indicator, dropbox

I upgraded from 10.10 to 11.04 today, so I'm using Unity now, and Dropbox has disappeared from the indicator area. It still works, but it's hard to use now.

I've already tried removing it and reinstalling from the site. I noticed that this readds the dropbox repository to the APT sources (the upgrade disabled it), but it's a maverick source.

How can I get it back?

Comment: I have it running fine on a clean 11.04 install and I confirm it does still show a `maverick` repo installed, so you can at least rule that out as part of the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have you checked if it's actually running? possibly you run a non-current release of dropbox, and just the indicator has vanished. dropbox only recently added indicator-applet compatibility, which is needed for natty.

upgrade dropbox by running

```
dropbox stop
rm -r ~/.dropbox-dist
dropbox start -i
```

*edit: not that bug after all, thx jorge. Seems to be fixed with a new dropbox version, though:
http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=37361&replies=20#post-315358*

Comment: Yes it's running. I'm also sure there was an indicator in 10.10, not a system tray icon. I have Dropbox 1.0.10

Comment: have you upgraded db yet? current general release version is 1.1.28, see https://www.dropbox.com/install

Comment: I assumed that having the Dropbox repo in there would upgrade it, but apparently not. Looks like only nautilus integration is in there, or something. Not very user friendly...

Comment: the repo is just for the nautilus integration component. db core updates are pulled directly from their server if you do what i posted above. (and per auto-update at the discretion of the db team, this should also work on linux. they are mega-cautious with that, though)

Comment: Yeah I just read that on their site. Anyway, I have 1.1.28 now.

Comment: so does it work correctly now? :-)

Comment: No, see my latest comment on the other answer :(

Comment: most probably this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/563632

Comment: A quick workaround for this bug could be to delay the dropbox start: In the startup applications dialog, change the entry from "dropbox start" to e.g. "sleep 40s && dropbox start". Can't test this though, still on 10.10.

Comment: I don't think that's the right bug, he's tagged it unity and unity doesn't use gnome-panel, could be something else.

Comment: Upgrading Dropbox worked for me the first time I did it. Then I had to re-install Maverick again and upgraded to Natty today. Dropbox icon is not shown anymore. I tried again upgrading it and restarting but it does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Dropbox themselves have just released today the their latest version with App Indicator support.

It should update automatically or [you can get it here](https://www.dropbox.com/install).

Comment: In the meantime I reenabled the system tray via the fix also mentioned in that article, and Dropbox showed up there. Then I followed these instructions and it stopped working. The icon is still there, but clicking (with any button) does nothing.

Comment: I'm very suspicious with that "system tray" fix - as you have found, if I enable the system tray, drop box and several other application indicators dont work.  I'm not using the "system tray" fix and drop-box works just fine.

Comment: Well, I undid that fix, then logged out and in, and it works now...almost. I need to stop/start it first, every time I log in :(

Comment: there's no need to manually pull and unzip the packages. 1.1.28 is a general release, see my answer...

Comment: That sounds like good news Christoph - I'll test this and amend my answer when I've confirmed.  Bart van Heukelom - add this "dropbox start -i" to a new entry in your "Startup Applications"

Comment: @Bart: sometimes when re-enabling the whole systray, appindicators stop working. It's a bug that still hasn't been fixed... Try to enable the systray only for a few apps.

Comment: @Alin Andrei: Ok I'll try that, but how do I find the correct names (that I have to put in the list) of my applications?

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
dropbox stop
mv ~/.dropbox-dist ~/DROPBOX-DIST  # backup, just in case!  :-)
sudo mv /var/lib/.dropbox-dist /var/lib/DROPBOX-DIST  # idem
dropbox start -i
```

It recreated `/var/lib/.dropbox-dist`

I have no `~/.dropbox-dist` now

Dropbox is working perfectly

Dropbox applet is working ok.